# How can I get a PathGeometry from text (not outlined/formatted)

Tags: wpf, text, geometry

In a custom `Shape` with a `PathGeometry`  as `DefiningGeometry` I want the `PathGeometry` to display a text.

I tried FormattedText but this looks like artistic text (like 3-d glyphs). I didn't realize that, probably a language barrier.
I want to create a `PathGeometry` from a text that looks like plain text, but still with Typeface, Fontsize, wight etc.

**How can I do that?** Can I give `BuildGeometry` a parameter?
I tried this:

```
PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();

FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface("Tahoma"), 12, Brushes.Black);
var geometrygroup = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point())as GeometryGroup;

if (geometrygroup != null)
{
    foreach (var child in geometrygroup.Children)
    {
        var line = child as GeometryGroup;

        if (line != null)
        {
            foreach (var glyph in line.Children)
            {
                var path = glyph as PathGeometry;
                if (path != null)
                {
                    geometry.AddGeometry(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
geometry.Transform = new TranslateTransform(20, 80);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom Shape class could be as simple as this:

```
public class TextShape : Shape
{
    public FormattedText Text { get; set; }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return Text.BuildGeometry(new Point()); }
    }
}
```

Just take care of setting its `Fill` property instead of `Stroke`.

---

Otherwise you can always create a `PathGeometry` from any other `Geometry` by simply calling [`GetFlattenedPathGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry.aspx) or [`GetOutlinedPathGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I wished live was always so easy.